# How to access the button inside ItemsControl->ItemTemplate->DataTemplate->StackPanel? wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

How can I get button in code behind from this structure in xaml?

```
<ItemsControl BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Name="cat1" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions[0]}" Margin="65,0,0,165">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="sp1">
                        <Button Width="60" Content="{Binding Points}" Height="30" Tag="{Binding Id}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"  Command="{Binding ElementName=cat1,  Path=DataContext.QuestionButtonClick}">

                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

- I tried to get stackpanel with name
- tried to get it from many `foreach`es

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. What is it you are trying to do?  Otherwise which button instance?  Show us your code attempt

Comment: The "Button" doesn't really exist until you add some items to the item control. What are you trying to do with the button? Seems like you need a command binding or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `VisualTreeHelper` to get the element on the current visual tree of your window.

For convenience, you can use the following extension method that can finds all children elements with the specified type or condition recursively on the visual tree.

```
public static class DependencyObjectExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetChildren<T>(this DependencyObject p_element, Func<T, bool> p_func = null) where T : UIElement
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(p_element); i++)
        {
            UIElement child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(p_element, i) as FrameworkElement;
            if (child == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (child is T)
            {
                var t = (T)child;
                if (p_func != null && !p_func(t))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                yield return t;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var c in child.GetChildren(p_func))
                {
                    yield return c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then when the window is loaded, you can get all the buttons like this:

```
var buttons = this.cat1.GetChildren<Button>().ToList();
```